All numeric ticker symbol in mutual fund monthly holdings
I am trying to understand Fidelity's Hedged Equity Fund (FEQHX).  The fund holds equities approximating the S&P500 and I think long dated out of the money puts.  They list their holdings as of September 20, 2024.  Each equity has a Ticker, CCUSIP, ISIN, and SEDOL, except for S&P 500 Index, which occurs 7 times.  The S&P 500 Index only has a numeric Ticker and no other codes.  For example "S&P 500 Index $419,160 0.170% 111684", where 111684 is in the Ticker column.  How can I look that up?
I am trying to get information from Fidelity, but so far they will not provide any information beyond the prospectus.
My purpose is to get a very rough idea of how the fund should react to a large downward market move of 5% or 10%.  So assuming that these are long dated puts with a value at a certain date, I should be able to figure out an approximate holding and the strike price.
Update:  I contacted Fidelity repeatedly.  One person thought that these were just S&P 500 positions, but another said that they were options.  I was never able to find out how to get quotes on them.

To look up the S&P 500 Index with the numeric ticker "111684," you might try using Fidelity’s fund details or their support team to clarify this specific index reference.
Since the index itself doesn’t usually have a standard ticker like equities, the numeric code may be an internal identifier.
As for gauging the fund's reaction to a large market drop, analyzing the specific puts (their strike prices and expiration dates) and their corresponding weights in the portfolio will give you insight into the hedging strategy.
Reaching out to Fidelity again or using other financial databases may help you get more specific data.
